# Rails, CanCan and Rolify: Postresql error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, cancan, rolify

Question for people who knows Rails with Cancan and Rolify gem. I want to understand how i can get list of user, that have some roles for (for example, Company).

Here is description with code and detailed description:

https://github.com/EppO/rolify/issues/260

Thanks for any ideas!

Vladimir

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you have to use

`@users = User.with_all_roles(:owner, :client, :manager, @company)`

instead of

`@users = User.with_role([:owner, :client, :manager], @company)`

Or if you can get all the users who has at least one of the roles: `has_any_role`

See more: https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Usage#finders-methods